# PhpWord running problem - no such file PhpWord.php

Tags: php, phpword

I try to run PhpWord on server but have issue.

**autoload.php**

```
<?php
function loadLibraries($class) {
    $path = __DIR__.'/lib/';
    require_once $path.$class.".php";
}

spl_autoload_register("loadLibraries");

?>
```

and here is my PHP script

**zml.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require "autoload.php";


// Create a new PHPWord object

use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();

// Add a section to the document
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Add some text to the section
$section->addText('Hello, World!');

// Save the document
$filename = 'hello_world.docx';
$phpWord->save($filename);

echo "Word document '$filename' has been created.";

?>
```

**Here is error:**

Warning: require_once(/zmluvy/lib/PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /zmluvy/autoload.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/zmluvy/lib/PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /zmluvy/autoload.php on line 4

**Location of files:**

autoload.php
/zmluvy/

zml.php
/zmluvy/

PhpWord.php
/zmluvy/lib/PhpOffice/PhpWord/

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have you run *composer install* on the server ?

Comment: @Pippo cant use ssh connection on server.

Comment: So you have to make sure that the phpWord package is installed on the server and possibly you have to do it manually